# How can I run rmmod from user space which doesn't have root(sudo) permission

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I am running a c program which requires system(rmmod usbserial) to be run.

I am able to run this application from root user which has sudo permission.

But I want to run from normal user space which doesn't have root or sudo permission.

How it can be done please suggest. Also I want to run it without typing sudo.

Like ./run_app instead of
sudo ./run_app

Comment: Why do you want to run this as a normal user, rather than root?

Comment: actually this application I am using is for changing the baudrare and the device driver conflicts with the default installed driver that's why each time user runs this program have to remove default driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it working by adding custom rules for the specific applications and it doesn't ask for root password from normal user space.